# iptables : how to block a user from accessing internet

Tags: iptables

how to block a user from accessing internet in linux.

Is the following command correct.

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80,443 -m owner --uid-owner $USERNAME -j DROP
```

Comment: should be on superuser..

Comment: yes .. I have the super user permissions, I want restrict internet access to some users for sometime.

Comment: superuser.com instead of stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that blocking http and https ports is not enough, however a user can use proxies or socks to by pass this restriction or may be some kinds of VPN.

The right way is to block all access to your users and permit all ports you need users to access.

Answer (score 1):

there are some many other back-door ports that can be used besides 80 & 443... you should be using the "on network" vs "off network" strategy:  block access to the IPs **not** part of the home LAN instead.  I am not sure how to express this using `iptables`... I would have to google-it and so can you  :-)